# Fast read of large text file to 1D structure in C++

Tags: c++, performance, io, ifstream

I need to read a batch of text files of up to 20mb in size, fast.

The text file comes in the format. The numbers need to be in double format as some other file may have 3 decimal place precision:

```
0 0 29 175 175 175 175 174 
0 1 29 175 175 175 175 174 
0 2 29 28 175 175 175 174 
0 3 29 28 175 175 175 174 
0 4 29 29 175 175 175 174
.
.
.
```

I would like to store the last six numbers of each line into a single 1D structure like this such that it skips the first two columns. It basically transposes each column and horizontally concatenates each transposed column:

```
29 29 29 29 29 175 175 28 28 29 175 175 175 175 175...
```

Here is my class attempting this that is too slow for my purposes.

```
void MyClass::GetFromFile(std::string filename, int headerLinestoSkip, int ColumnstoSkip, int numberOfColumnsIneed)
{
std::ifstream file(filename);   
std::string file_line;
double temp;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> temp_vector(numberOfColumnsIneed);

if(file.is_open())
{   
    SkipLines(file, headerLinestoSkip);
    while(getline(file, file_line, '\n'))
    {   
        std::istringstream ss(file_line);
        for(int i=0; i<ColumnstoSkip; i++)
        {
            ss >> temp;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<numberOfColumnsIneed; i++)
        {
            ss >> temp;
            temp_vector[i].push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<numberOfColumnsIneed; i++)
    {
        this->ClassMemberVector.insert(this->ClassMemberVector.end(), temp_vector[i].begin(), temp_vector[i].end());
    }

}
```

I have read that memory mapping the file may be helpful but my attempts to getting it into the 1D structure I need has not been successful. An example from someone would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Because of the way you use the vector of vectors, the data will not be sequential the way you seemingly want them. Instead the data will become something like `29 29 29 29 ... 175 175 28 28 29 ...` etc. Use a debugger and step through the code, line by line, to see why.

Comment: Also, do you know how many lines there will be in the file? Have you tried checking how effective it is to count the lines first, and then reserving the space for the final resulting vector and reading directly into it?

Comment: You are correct about the sequence. I edit to correct myself. There is a chance that the number of  lines in all files are not the same so I may need it in my class.

Comment: Have you profiled your `GetFromFile()` method to see where it's actually taking time?  On the same hardware it's going to run on when it's operational?

Answer (score 1):

With 20mb and short lines as you show, that's approx 500 000 lines.  Knowing this, there are several factors that could slow down your code:

- I/O : at the current hardware and OS performance, I can't imagine that this plays a role here;
- parsing/conversion. You read each line, build a string stream out of it, to then extract the numbers.  This could be an overhead, especially on some C++ implementations where stream extraction is slower than the old `sscanf()`.  I may be wrong but again I'm not sure that this overhead would be so huge.
- the memory allocation for your vectors.  This is definitely the first place to look for.  A vector has a size and a capacity.  Each time you add an item above capacity, the vector needs to be reallocated, which could require to move and move again all its content.

I'd strongly advise you to execute your code with a profiler to identify the bottleneck.  Manual timing will be difficult here because your loop contains all potential problems, but each iteration is certainly to quick for [std::chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) to measure the different loop parts with sufficient accuracy.

If you can't use a profiler, I'd suggest to compute a rough estimation of the number of lines using the file size, and take half of it. [Pre-reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) then the corresponding capacity in each `temp_vector[i]`.  If you observe a good progress you'll be the right track and could then fine tune this approach. If not, edit your answer with your new findings and post a comment to this answer.

Comment: *I/O : at the current hardware and OS performance, I can't imagine that this plays a role here;*  Oh?!?!  A RAID array of high-end SSDs connected by a good hardware controller isn't going to be orders of magnitude faster than a single S-L-O-W 5,400 RPM commodity-grade SATA drive?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Don't misunderstand me:  I fully agree that there is a whole range of magnitude differences among hardware.  But - 1) I assume that OP thinks it's slow compared to other I/O operations on his machine  - 2) we are on the megabyte level, so with an [average hdd](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/hdd-charts-2013/-02-Read-Throughput-Maximum-h2benchw-3.16,2900.html) the read time should still be too small to be noticed as bottleneck.